# How to compute derivative of activation function involving division

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I am implementing a neural network a bit different from the standard architectures. Nevertheless, the implementation should be efficient and vectorized.

Consider that a layer has an activation function *ln(X)*. Thus, backpropagation would compute the derivative *1/X*.
Now, that is the problem: how do I compute the division? I know I could multiply by the inverse of *X*, but this shouldn't work, since I can't guarantee that *X* is a square matrix.

Any thoughts on this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confused between matrix operations and element-wise operations. Vectorizing your computations does not mean they should be matrix operations, they can also be element-wise operations. It only means that you give the computer an instruction that applies an operation to a vector of numbers instead of a separate instruction per number.

In your case, you want element-wisr division. Each unit has its own activation $ln(x) $ and you want to compute the derivative of that per unit. Depending on your language you can find out how to compute $\vec{1} \backslash \vec{x} $ where $\vec{1}$ is a vector of one's, $\vec{x} $ is the data and $\backslash$ is element-wise division.

Examples of element-wise division:

- Matlab `x ./ y`
- Python `numpy.divide(x, y)`
- R `x / y`
- TensorFlow `tf.div(x, y)`

Comment: Thank you, @Pieter. Indeed I misunderstood that. Just to make sure, does this idea also apply in case you are dividing two matrices? For instance, consider _X / Y_, where _X_ is a matrix of shape, say, `(2,3)` while _Y_ is `(2,1)`. That is, can I equivalently perform `X.T dot 1/Y`?

Comment: You can only element-wise divide, multiply, add or subtract or whatever if the matrices or vectors have the same size.